# Apply an opacity mask with CSS3

Tags: html, css, svg, webkit, mask

I'm trying to apply a CSS Mask to fade a DIV horizontally in both direction.
I created the mask with an online editor and it works smoothly using `-webkit-mask` and base64 encoding:

```css
#slicenter{-webkit-mask: url(data:image/png;base64,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);}
```

The problem is: this works just on Chrome (and maybe Safari).

So I tried to export the same image to HTML/SVG. This is what I got:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="200px" >
<defs> 
<linearGradient id="lgrad" x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" > 
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:0" />
<stop offset="5%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
<stop offset="95%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:0" />
</linearGradient> 
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#lgrad)"/>
</svg>
```

And then I tried to convert this vector in a mask (but it's probably wrong):

```html
 <svg height="0" >
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="g" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" > 
   <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:0" />
   <stop offset="5%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
   <stop offset="95%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
   <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:0" />
  </linearGradient> 
  <mask id="lgrad" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"> 
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#g)"/>
  </mask>
 </defs>
 </svg>
```

I applied the mask to the same element with:

```css
#slicenter{mask: url(#lgrad);}
```

But it doesn't works. Any Ideas?
Cheers

Comment: Is #slicenter{mask: url(#lgrad);} in a CSS file if so that's your problem as #lgrad is short for `<this file>`#lgrad and there's no lgrad in the CSS file.

Comment: I didn't think about it. Thanks!
Still, I think the SVG code is broken anyway: I put the css code inside the php file, and now the DIV it's completely blank.